# Most simple "get started" with jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to get going with JMeter, and am having trouble finding a really simple tutorial for the first "getting started" the docs seem to be very verbose, covering all kinds of scenarios.

Can anyone point me at something that would take me from having downloaded the app (I can run it, and get a gui) to the point where I can send a single, predefined GET request, at a specific rate.

Just one request, no login, nothing. But I'd like to be able to send it at a selected rate.

This will do two things for me, first, get past that wall of info that I'm finding and give me a starting point from which to experiment. Second, it's actually pretty much all I want to do anyway; I don't want to record results, I just want to hit a server at specific steady state rates, and observe the OS level impact on the server when it stabilizes (number of threads, memory usage, rate of context switching, cpu usage). I'll get to more complex things later, maybe.

I'm sure someone has written something to achieve this, but google keeps finding heavyweight "tomes" that are off-putting to wade through and feel like they're wasting huge amounts of my time :(

(Oh, and I did search here, but only found more complex stuff; hope I didn't get egg on my face with a duplicate!)

TIA,
Toby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find Blazemeter's JMeter tutorial to be very beginner friendly:

http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/topics/10018-jmeter-tutorials

http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/197560-jmeter-video-tutorial-writing-your-first-jmeter-s

(I'm not affiliated with Blazemeter)

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the simplest JMeter Test Plan as per your scenario should be something like:

- [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) - to set a number of threads and iterations

  - [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) - to configure endpoint, path, parameters, etc.

    - [Constant Throughput Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) - to set exact desired request execution rate (N requests per second)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Gach, as so often is the case, the terminology was obscuring that first level of understanding that allows one to make use of the docs. I found what I needed right there in the regular documentation:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html

Comment: Also found this to be fairly helpful. It's broader based, talking a bit about some background, but gets to the point fairly promptly:
http://www.davegardner.me.uk/blog/2010/09/23/effective-load-testing-with-apache-jmeter/